# Generating a table from another excel table

Tags: excel

In the excel sheet there are two columns, Col1 contains alphabets, Col2 contains numerical value corresponding to that alphabets.

Can i generate another table (from this table) which only show, Just one occurrence of each alphabet with total of that particular Alphabet.

This is excel sheet.

(this is a vertical sheet)

```
Col1 Col2
A   12
B   45
C   12
D   65
A   45
B   12
D   85
C   74
C   5
D   6
B   45
A   7
E   8
F   9
E   8
F   8
A   55
D   65
C   25
B   74
B   58
B   24
C   74
D   12
D   32
B   56
```

Since the table is not viewed properly, here is the image of table.

[image]

For example: B is 7 times in this table, and total value corresponding to B is 314.

so a table can be generated as

```
A  ... (Total of all A)
B  314
C  ... (Total of all C)
D  ... (Total of all D)and so on.
```

Comment: consider about using [pivot table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I see three solutions:

1. You can use pivot tables: Select the data range then click Insert > Pivot table and just show the sum of col B for col A as row data;
2. You can use the SUMIF() Excel formula. The first parameter is the range for the criteria (col A), the second is the value to check for (A2, A3..) and the last parameter is the data over which to sum (col B)
3. Similar to SUMIF() there is also SUMPRODUCT() which has a little more complex syntax:

   =SUMPRODUCT((criteria_range=criteria)*(sum_range))